# Failed to stop postfix.service: Unit postfix.service not loaded

Tags: apt, 16.04, postfix

When I try to remove `postfix` I get this error:

```
Removing postfix (3.1.0-3) ...
Failed to stop postfix.service: Unit postfix.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript postfix, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason was because `/etc/init.d/postfix` did not exist.

I created a blank `/etc/init.d/postfix` file and made it executable using `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/postfix`, then problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me:

After creating a postfix file, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge postfix
```

And then reinstall postfix:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install postfix
```

Comment: This works for me. Though don't know why :) Thanks

Comment: This also works for my setup. everything I tried failed but this one worked fine. Thanks alot. --reinstall did it.